# What do I have to do so I can get 2 users to be able to access disk drives / partitions at the same time?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, permissions, encryption, mount

I mounted a disk drive using UserA ==> /run/media/userA/myDisk .

userB is a member of the same group of userA.

Why can userB not access the mountpoints?

What do I have to do so I can get 2 users to be able to access disk drives / partitions at the same time?

Also to note the disks are encrypted.

I do not want chmod the files or directory to 777

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this unusual mount point? In any case, please include the output of `mount` in your question.

Comment: @DanielB: The mount point is normal. It's the default location used by `udisks2` for users' personal removable media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

udisks2 intentionally makes removable devices private to the user. (By design, Linux is a multi-user system, and can potentially have several people having separate seats (displays, keyboards, USB ports) and connecting their own USB drives, so they should be separate from each other.) So all per-user directories under `/run/media` are limited to their owner only.

- To make udisks2 place all mountpoints under `/media`, which it used to do in the past, you can install a n udev rule by placing the following in `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-udisks2-shared.rules`:

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"
  ```

  Alternatively, you could move a specific device by configuring it in `/etc/fstab`, e.g.:

  ```
  /dev/mapper/luks-backups /mnt/backup auto noauto,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show
  ```

  In fact, you *should* always use `/etc/fstab` for internal or otherwise fixed disks.
- However, this will only allow other users to reach the mountpoint, it will not automatically allow them to browse files inside – you *will* need to change the files' permissions. This depends on the filesystem your disk is using.

  If you use ext4, btrfs, or generally any filesystem that supports Unix file ownership & permissions, use `groupadd` to create a dedicated group for users allowed to access the disk; `gpasswd -a` to add them to the group; then mount the disk and `chown -R` it to the newly created group. Use `chmod -R g+rwX` to make all files group-accessible, and `find /mnt/disk -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +` to make them inherit the group ownership.

  If you use fat32/vfat, do the same, but changing ownership or permissions will not work; instead, you will need to add the `gid=...` mount option in `/etc/fstab`. (The option should have the actual ID of the group that you just added.)